# Are American universities letting international students start their PhDs from their home countries?

Tags: phd, united-states, international, covid-19

Due to the ongoing Covid-19 pandemic, not only international traveling but also obtaining visas is very difficult and sometimes impossible, depending on the country. Are American universities accepting international students that are in such predicament and allowing them to work from home (in this case, their home country)?

Comment: This would be an individual thing. Some university might allow it in an individual case. You can ask, but it is fairly unlikely. Especially if you have only a bachelors degree.

Comment: @Buffy do you say it's fairly unlikely based on experience with similar requests or on your general experience of how the "system" works?

Comment: Just general experience (hence not an answer). A doctorate in US normally starts with coursework. That might make it easier if the courses are online (and the time difference can be managed). But ask.

Comment: My question was closed because "it strongly depends on individual factors". That is very vague and I tend to disagree. Also, the personal feedback has nothing to do with what I was looking for or with my wording of the question. Can it be reopened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you will need a visa in order to get any of your tuition covered either by a fellowship, research funding, or teaching assistantship. Tuition without remission can be very expensive in the US, usually much larger than the stipend you actually end up being paid to live on.

My best guess is that if you are accepted, you can defer your start date until your visa comes through. This way you won't have to enroll and pay tuition before you can get "paid" by the university though tuition payments.

Also, your visa might come through! I moved internationally September 2020 for a postdoc, and all my paperwork came together in time. Neither the country I lived in last year nor the country I live in now are my home country of citizenship. Covid did cause some complications, but both governments were understanding, and in the end everything was approved.

Edited: check out the comments. Apparently some (maybe many?) universities ARE able to cover tuition without a visa! This wouldn't have been my guess, but that's great for international students! In any case, start talking to your dept. If they can cover you, great, if not, you'll still need to talk to them about the possibility/process of deferring.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed I was accepted but the American embassy in my country suspended all visa interviews, so I'm not even able to start the process of obtaining a visa right now.

Comment: This is not accurate. We can't pay salaries to people who are working remotely in other countries, but tuition waivers are not affected. Obviously there are some fields where working remotely is not possible, but you should speak to the department immediately.

Comment: I know of at least one university that allowed remote starts last fall (with tuition remission). Seems less likely by this fall, with most colleges I know of planning on full in-person activities.

Comment: @JonCuster We're intending to be fully in-person in the fall, but the current guidance is that we'll still be flexible with international students on an individual basis at least for the fall semester. What that means is, of course, open to a lot of interpretation...

Comment: @Libor - indeed, and the whole applying for a visa thing looks to be be very problematic. Situation normal, all confusing for the moment. Flexibility is likely, but bureaucrats are not known for it.